# Nested do ....while loops in access vba

Tags: vba

I am trying to run through all the records in an access table using nested do ...while loops.

There is varying criteria for each loop so I am opening up multiple recordsets before I run the loops.

When I run the code, it is working as it should, however the problem is when 1 of the recordsets has no records the whole process fails.

Here is the bit of code for the nested loops.

```
    Dim rst1, rst2, rst3, rst4, rst5, rst6 As Recordset
Dim sqlSt1, sqlSt2, sqlSt3, sqlSt4, sqlSt5, sqlSt6 As String
Dim rcdCount, a, b, c, d, e, f As Double

Set dbs = CurrentDb
sqlSt1 = "SELECT * FROM [Rune List - Optimizer List] WHERE [Rune Slot]= 1"
sqlSt2 = "SELECT * FROM [Rune List - Optimizer List] WHERE [Rune Slot]= 2"
sqlSt3 = "SELECT * FROM [Rune List - Optimizer List] WHERE [Rune Slot]= 3"
sqlSt4 = "SELECT * FROM [Rune List - Optimizer List] WHERE [Rune Slot]= 4"
sqlSt5 = "SELECT * FROM [Rune List - Optimizer List] WHERE [Rune Slot]= 5"
sqlSt6 = "SELECT * FROM [Rune List - Optimizer List] WHERE [Rune Slot]= 6"

Set rst1 = dbs.OpenRecordset(sqlSt1)
Set rst2 = dbs.OpenRecordset(sqlSt2)
Set rst3 = dbs.OpenRecordset(sqlSt3)
Set rst4 = dbs.OpenRecordset(sqlSt4)
Set rst5 = dbs.OpenRecordset(sqlSt5)
Set rst6 = dbs.OpenRecordset(sqlSt6)

startTime = Time

rcdCount = rst1.recordCount
SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter, "Processing: ", rcdCount

Debug.Print "4: " & rst4.recordCount
Debug.Print "6: " & rst6.recordCount


Do While Not rst1.EOF And Not rst1.BOF
    Do While Not rst2.EOF And Not rst2.BOF
        Do While Not rst3.EOF And Not rst3.BOF
            Do While Not rst4.EOF And Not rst4.BOF
                Do While Not rst5.EOF And Not rst5.BOF
                    Do While Not rst6.EOF And Not rst6.BOF

                        f = f + 1
                        rst6.MoveNext
                    Loop

                    e = e + 1
                    rst6.MoveFirst
                    rst5.MoveNext
                Loop

                d = d + 1
                rst5.MoveFirst
                rst4.MoveNext
            Loop

            c = c + 1
            rst4.MoveFirst
            rst3.MoveNext
        Loop

        b = b + 1
        rst3.MoveFirst
        rst2.MoveNext
    Loop

    a = a + 1
    SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, a
    DoEvents

    rst2.MoveFirst
    rst1.MoveNext
Loop
rst1.Close
rst2.Close
rst3.Close
rst4.Close
rst5.Close
rst6.Close

SysCmd acSysCmdRemoveMeter

endTime = Time

tmDuration = DateDiff("s", CDate(startTime), CDate(endTime))
tm = Format(Int([tmDuration] / 3600), "00") & ":" & Format(Int(([tmDuration] - (Int([tmDuration] / 3600) * 3600)) / 60), "00") & ":" & Format((([tmDuration] Mod 60)), "00")

Debug.Print a
Debug.Print b
Debug.Print c
Debug.Print d
Debug.Print e
Debug.Print f
Debug.Print "-----------------"
Debug.Print tm
```

Is there an easy way I can check for empty records and skip the ones that will cause problems?

Thanks for any help

K

Comment: By "empty records" i assume you mean empty recordsets.  Check if rst#.eof = false then.  I would refactor this so they are not all nested like that.  If you post more of your code maybe somebody can suggest better logic.

Comment: "The whole process fails" tells us nothing.  Tell us what is actually wrong.  Also, show us the actual code that is failing, as the above appears to be correct.

Comment: When it fails does the table actually exist in the recordset?

Comment: Yes it does evaluate to an empty recordset. I am building a list of permutations based of the 6 recordsets I am using. The code needs to run through each recordset in each of the nested loops, it needs to do this to build the permutations. There can be anywhere between 0 & 50 records in each recordset. If as an example rst4 has an empty recordset it doesn't pass through to rst5 and pops up a message with 'no records'. If they all contain records the process is fine and finishes, its only when there is no records in any one of the recordsets.

Answer (score 0):

it appears all you want are counts.  Why not use formulas instead of loops.

```
f = rst6.recordcount * rst5.recordcount * ...
e = rst5.recordcount * rst4.recordcount * ...
```

do this for all six variables.  Realize that if rst4.recordcount is 0 then you will get 0 for d,e,f.  But by the way you are coding that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking guys, I realised yesterday the code is actually working as it should, if there is 0 records in any of the recordsets then it shouldn't be running the nested loops anyway.

Thanks again.